# Node.js Only Displays " ... " when i try and execute files

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok Whenever I use Node.js, I can execute inline code like: **console.log('Hello World');** , Perfectly but, when i try and use: **node test/test.js** or **node test.js**, It looks like this:
>**node** test/test.js

**...**
And thats all I get!!! I could never get it to work. I would appreciate it tremendously, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you started node by running the executable itself. In this mode you can run the javascript commands directly. But people usually running node scripts from the terminal (Linux/Mac) or command prompt (Windows) as follows:

```
C:\>node test/test.js
```

Where C:\ is a path to the current working folder.